# Retrieve data on multi-zone DVD?

Tags: dvd, merge, dvd-burning, border

I had some data on a DVD.  I wanted to add a file to it.

I opened up Roxio Creator DE and it said that it was Appendable.  I appended the file and now all the old data doesn't show up when reading the DVD (on Windows XP).

When I use Roxio to display "Disc Information", it shows the following:

```
DVD-R, Open, Multiborder, Data Appendable
Border 1
  01 - Zone - DVD1  0:00 (000000) *{Start}*   3,389.9 MB (1735648) *{Length}*  
Border 2
  02 - Zone - DVD1  396:10 (1782768)           1.2 MB (000631)
```

The above information shows that my old data exists in "Border 1".

How can I merge the two zones so that my appended data shows up with the previous data?

IOW, merge Border 1 with Border 2.  I am open to creating a new DVD with **all** the data on it in one visible section.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution is to obtain a tool (application) that can read all of the data sections on the DVD, then create a new one.